# How does compilation reserve space in stack?

Tags: c++, c, memory, compilation, hardware

I don't have much knowledge in computers, so my questions are quite naive.

I learned that compilation of a C code reserves specific memory space in stack in the main memory during compilation.

Then,

1. Why does an executable work when it is compiled in one computer copied over to another computer?
2. If compilation reserve specific memory location of RAM, then are the number of executables (or compilation) limited by size of the RAM?
3. If compilation reserves space in RAM, why does an executable occupy a lot more disk space than pre-compilation .C text file?

Thank you

Comment: Short answer: However it wants. The C standard doesn't force you to do anything, nor even have a stack at all. In practice, some operating systems [have default settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/stack-stack-allocations?view=msvc-170) when running executables of *any* language. If you want to learn more, [here's an example about Rust](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8irLfXwaFM) which explains what happens *before* your `main()` function runs. There's actually a lot going on in your executable.

Comment: Compilation doesn't reserve space while you're compiling. It generates code that does this when the program is loaded. The program can be loaded onto a different computer.

Comment: There is no simple one-paragraph answer to any of your questions. If you really want to understand this, take the [NAND to Tetris](https://www.nand2tetris.org/) course.

Comment: This is the essential difference between compilers and interpreters. Compilers generate code that can be executed later, potentially on a different computer. Interpreters execute the code immediately.

Comment: After compilation your program executable code and some data that can be known at compile time. This code and fixed data (executable can be quite large if there is a lot of this kind of data) are loaded into memory (code can be loaded into memory which is write protected). Then the operating looks for info on what address the first instruction of the program is and starts there. Then when calls are made local variables of a function (are on most computers) put on the stack.

Comment: @Barnar not quite, if you have static variables then they do take up space in your executable (try a large static array if you want to see that for yourself)

Comment: @PepijnKramer So it is reserving the space on the disk, not in RAM. The RAM becomes reserved once the executable is loaded

Comment: Read carefully, not ALL memory a program needs is reserved on disk. only the memory needed by static variables. Local variables (on most systems) end up on the stack, and dynamically allocated memory (new/delete/std::make_unique) end up somewhere in RAM (usually called the heap).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The stack is not *reserved* by the compiler in the compilation time. It is reserved in a sense that the compiler is inserting specific commands and directives into the executable, for the stack to be reserved when the executable is being loaded/run
2. No. See above. The RAM is not *reserved* (that is made unavailable to other executables) at a time of compilation. It is reserved when the executable is being loaded/executed.
3. This is not necessarily true. In many case the executable is smaller than the code. But it can depend on many factors, such as how the code is written, the executable format, metadata included in it and memory layout. Sometimes the executable will contain whole zero-filled sections, which can be defined by a single line in the code.

In general, a compiler (in conjunction with linker whatsoever, if we want to be pedantic) has only one "simple" job - to take input files (code) and generate output file(s) - the executable. That is - it is creating files, that are only occupying space in the file system. Other things can happen only when the environment (OS) is loading and doing *something* (loading, executing) with them.

Comment: Question#2 is also caused by not knowing about virtual memory

Comment: *to take input files (code) and generate output file(s)* -> Or as I was once told, the compiler takes human readable code and turns it into machine readable code

Comment: @NathanOliver I happened to see some source code which wasn't human-readable at all :)

Answer (score 1):

The space is not reserved during compilation. During compilation, there are instructions generated that, when executed at runtime, will take space on the stack.

For example, when you declare a variable in your code:

```
int x = 5;
```

The compiler will emit instructions that push 4 bytes (let's assume that is the size of `int`) onto the stack. But this is happening at runtime. That space is reserved when this line of code is reached at runtime. The caveat here is that an optimizing compiler could do all kinds of things here and may not actually allocate stack space.

It works when you copy the executable to another machine because the stack reservation is going to happen on that machine as the code is executed.

The number of executables that can be running at a time is going to depend on the amount of memory. Note that many OS's will swap memory between RAM and an available hard disk if you run out of memory. This increases how many executables can be ran, but the system will generally slow down a lot when this occurs.